# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] only working in htdocs not sub-folder

Tags: php, apache

I am not a PHP dev so please excuse any dumb question i might ask.

I am trying to move a php website from htdocs root in to a sub folder. but when I do this it breaks the paths.

example:

www.mysite.com/subfolder/index.php

the include path are currently set up like

```
<?php include(''.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/config.php'); ?>
```

and

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

How can I get it to work from a subfolder?

Answer (score 2):

You can make paths relative to the PHP application itself, not to document root

```
<?php include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.php'); ?>
```

and

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
```

or in newer versions of PHP, instead of `dirname(__FILE__)` you can use `__DIR__`

Comment: `__DIR__` was added in PHP 5.3.0

Comment: hi Peeyush, I am getting a mesaage Notice: Use of undefined constant __DIR__ - assumed '__DIR__' in E:\domains\n\XXXXXXX.co.uk\user\htdocs\pb\config\config.php on line 20

Answer (score 0):

You can set the path where your PHP scripts are looking for include files using the [set_include_path()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) function. You can also set this in your .htaccess file. You can find more information in this forum post:

http://www.aota.net/forums/showthread.php?t=23193